# Pass arguments to executable in Python

Tags: python

I am using `os.startfile('C:\\test\\sample.exe')` to launch the application. I don't want to know the application’s exit status and I just want to launch the exe.

I need to pass the argument to that exe like `'C:\\test\\sample.exe' -color`

Please suggest a method to run this in Python.

Comment: use `os.system("command")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html) module instead of `os.startfile` or `os.system` in every case that I'm aware of.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([r'C:\test\sample.exe', '-color'])
```

You *could*, as @Hackaholic suggests in the comments, do

```
import os
os.system(r'C:\test\sample.exe -color')
```

But this is no simpler, and [the docs for `os`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.system) recommend the use of `subprocess` instead.

Comment: subprocess is waiting for the new exe to complete but my objective is just to launch new exe. below code is not working. os.system(r'c:\\Program Files\\bin\\winx64\\sample.exe -b -color')

Comment: @Bala Ah, right, forgot that `os.startfile` opens in a new process. I've edited my answer; you should use `subprocess.Popen` if you don't want the call to block.

Comment: @Bala Note also: you should either use double slashes `'C:\\foo'` _OR_ raw strings `r'C:\foo'`. Not both. If you use both, you will have too many backslashes in your file paths. That is probably why the `os.system` call in your comment is failing.

Comment: The following options are not working. Please suggest:   subprocess.Popen(['C:\data\ANSYS.exe -b -i cdb_wb.txt'])                               subprocess.check_call([r'C:\data\ANSYS.exe', '-b -i cdb_wb.txt'])

Comment: @Bala You should probably pass each flag and argument separately, so that your argument list looks something like `[r'C:\data\ANSYS.exe', '-b', '-i', 'cdb_wb.txt']`. If this doesn't work for you, please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

Create a batch file `sam_ple.bat` with the following commands and arguments

```
cd C:\test\
start sample.exe -color
```

Then put `sam_ple.bat` in the same directory as your script.py file

Enter the following line of code in python to launch the exe:

```
os.startfile('.\sam_ple.bat')
```