# How to open an exe file which has many parameters?

Tags: python, exe

I want to call an EXE file which has arguments. The python code I have, can open the EXE file . Since it has arguments, only the blank command prompt opens and closes within few seconds.

I want the code for, how to open the EXE file in python which can be opened only using command prompt.
(i.e., double click on the EXE file doesn't work, because I can not provide any parameters. double click == calling without arguments == just producing a command line output that is not shown since the terminal is directly closed.)

Below is the code I used for opening the normal exe file, which only gives me the blank command prompt without opening the application.

```
import os
os.startfile(r"C:\Users\vinya\Downloads\Inta-64bit\Inta-64bit\Inta.exe")
```

Please help me with the code for opening the exe file which has many arguments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass arguments to executable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680647/pass-arguments-to-executable-in-python)

Comment: Use `os.system()` or `subprocess.call()` instead of `os.startfile()`. The documentation describes how to pass parameters.

Comment: There are many arguments in the application. I need to use arguments depending on the need. so, i want the code which can directly call the exe file which opens via command prompt